# Rails id array inclusion validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, validation

I want to check whether an ID value coming from user included in the array of acceptable values or not.

It's clear for me that it's coming like a string, e.g "135", "148", and  the array of values is presented like number array ([135,148,191]).

So, I do:

```
validates :pay_type, inclusion: { in: PaymentType.ids.map(&:to_s) }
```

Is there any way to get rid from this uneven `.map(&:to_s)` method every time I want to perform this kind of check?

*Update:* Changing `pay_type` type in database from `string` to `integer` solved the problem. Thanks for all.

Comment: Are you rebuilding a foreign-key constraint in Rails? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: is `ids` a class method of `PaymentType `, what's `PaymentType`? model?

Comment: `ids` fetches out all the ids of the PaymentType class -> AFAICS the OP is trying to check that the pay_type is one of those ids... this is exactly what a foreign-key constraint does and should be done in the DB using SQL, not through ruby.

Comment: @stepler645 : It's better you change the column type of `pay_type` from `string` to `integer` bcz there is not any meaning to store digits as string in db. When you fetch the data that time you have to convert it in integer again.

Comment: why not something like PaymentType.find(array_of_ids_in_integer_or_string) .. although you have to catch the exception raised

Comment: Yeah, Gagan was right, the problem was that column type of `pay_type` was `string`, not `integer`.